# Can I "branch" stream into many and write them in parallel in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am receiving Kafka stream in pyspark. Currently I am grouping it by one set of fields and writing updates to database:

```
df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
        .option("subscribe", topic)

...

df = df \
        .groupBy("myfield1") \
        .agg(
            expr("count(*) as cnt"),
            min(struct(col("mycol.myfield").alias("mmm"), col("*"))).alias("minData")
        ) \
        .select("cnt", "minData.*") \
        .select(
            col("...").alias("..."),
            ...
            col("userId").alias("user_id")

query = df \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .foreachBatch(lambda df, epoch: write_data_frame(table_name, df, epoch)) \
        .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Can I take the same chain in the middle and create another grouping like

```
df2 = df \
        .groupBy("myfield2") \
        .agg(
            expr("count(*) as cnt"),
            min(struct(col("mycol.myfield").alias("mmm"), col("*"))).alias("minData")
        ) \
        .select("cnt", "minData.*") \
        .select(
            col("...").alias("..."),
            ...
            col("userId").alias("user_id")
```

and write it's ooutput into different place in parallel?

Where to call `writeStream` and `awaitTermination`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can branch a Kafka input stream into as many streaming queries as you like.

You need to consider the following:

1. `query.awaitTermination` is a blocking method, which means whatever code you are writing after this method will not be executed until this `query` gets terminated.
2. Each "branched" streaming query will run in parallel and is it important that you define a checkpoint location in each of their writeStream calls.

Overall, your code needs to have the following structure:

```py
df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .[...]

# note that I changed the variable name to "df1"
df1 = df \
    .groupBy("myfield1") \
    .[...]

df2 = df \
    .groupBy("myfield2") \
    .[...]


query1 = df1 \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpointLoc1") \
        .foreachBatch(lambda df, epoch: write_data_frame(table_name, df1, epoch)) \
        .start()

query2 = df2 \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpointLoc2") \
        .foreachBatch(lambda df, epoch: write_data_frame(table_name, df2, epoch)) \
        .start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination
```

Just an additional remark: In the code you are showing, you are overwriting `df`, so the derivation of `df2` might not get you the results as you were intended.